# How to disallow any application from stealing focus in Awesome WM?

Tags: arch-linux, awesome

It seems that any new windows are given focus by default, and that's fine. However, some applications steal focus at other times. For example, JetBrains IDEA does this several times during start-up. Is it possible to avoid this focus stealing?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent programs from stealing focus in Awesome WM, add this line to your rc.lua:

```
awful.ewmh.add_activate_filter(function() return false end, "ewmh")
awful.ewmh.add_activate_filter(function() return false end, "rules")
```

The first line adds a filter that rejects any requests issued by already-open programs to "steal" the focus (these requests have context "ewmh").

The second line adds a filter to prevent newly-opened applications from stealing focus (context "rules").

See the [documentation for `add_activate_filter`](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/awful.ewmh.html#awful.ewmh.add_activate_filter) for more info.

> The line at the top is equivalent to the following code (but it's a bit cleaner):
>
> ```
> function filter_activation(c, context, hints)
>     if context == 'ewmh' or context == 'rules' then
>         return false
>     else
>         return true
>     end
>  end
>  awful.ewmh.add_activate_filter(filter_activation)
> ```

Comment: That doesn't work. To reproduce using my configuration (with your line), simply show the "shell" tag on one screen with the terminal on, show the "dev" tag on the other screen, focus the terminal, and wait for IDEA to start up and steal focus.

Comment: @l0b0 wow. Ok, I give up. I recently switched from IntelliJ to VS Code but I downloaded it just to try this out. I checked the context (`"ewmh"` in the code above) for IntelliJ's `request:activate` signals and there was one for `"rules"`, but even after disabling this, and disabling "urgent" as mentioned in another answer, IntelliJ still manages to steal the focus, and I can't for the life of me figure out why or how. Best guess is that IntelliJ is requesting focus and OpenJDK is forcing focus directly in X, bypassing Awesome.

Comment: The solution does work in **almost** every case.

Comment: Except for the one in the question :)

Comment: @l0b0 unfortunately! Although it does say "any application"

Answer (score -1):

**From the [API documentation](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/documentation/90-FAQ.md.html):**
Why are new clients urgent by default?

You can change this by redefining awful.ewmh.activate(c) in your rc.lua. If you don't want new clients to be urgent by default put this in your rc.lua:

```
client.disconnect_signal("request::activate", awful.ewmh.activate)
function awful.ewmh.activate(c)
    if c:isvisible() then
        client.focus = c
        c:raise()
    end
end
client.connect_signal("request::activate", awful.ewmh.activate)
```

Comment: This doesn't work (as in, after restarting Awesome and launching IDEA, it steals focus multiple times). I also don't really want to change the default behaviour for every application, I just want IDEA not to be able to steal focus after the main window has been created.

Comment: This didn't work for me, either, but I figured out how to do it

Comment: I know this is straight out of the docs, but this prevents restoring minimised windows, at least on Awesome 4.3.